Twilio Debugging Events Webhook not sending complete Flex UI error message
We're using Debugging Events Webhook to send Twilio Error logs to CloudWatch so we can better summarize and analyze errors from Twilio.
We're not getting the complete error message for Flex UI errors (45600) though. For example, the webhook only receives the following from Twilio (ids are redacted):
{
    "Payload": {
        "resource_sid": "WK...",
        "service_sid": "WS...",
        "error_code": "45600"
    },
    "Level": "ERROR",
    "Timestamp": "2024-11-04T15:31:10.479061Z",
    "PayloadType": "application/json",
    "AccountSid": "AC...",
    "Sid": "NO..."
}

But for the same Error Sid, we can see a complete JavaScript error with stack trace in the Twilio Console:

(I'm not concerned about the Flex UI error in itself, but the fact that the complete error message, highlighted in the screenshot above, is only available in the Twilio Console and not in the event sent to the webhook)
How can we receive the complete error message in the Debugging Events Webhook too?

Have you added the more_info property in the payload parameter of the debugging events webhook? Reference https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/troubleshooting/debugging-event-webhooks

@VictorGonzalezChamorro how do I enable the more_info? I've set up the webhook at https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/debugger/webhook and all I can configure is the Webhook callback URL.

Sorry, my bad @ericbn. You can't enable that, it should arrive in the request if the error payload add it when it's sent. In this case it looks like it's not added. What I would recommend now is to migrate to  Event Streams
using webhooks https://www.twilio.com/docs/events/webhook-quickstart . That's the future of events logging in twilio.
